# Define strong-typed variables in Python

Tags: python, strong-typing

Intellisence can't able help with Python members of an object because the object type will only be known at runtime. Is there a way to specify the type of the variable?

E.g.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(x).getroot()
for data in root.findall('./data'):
    data.
```

Is there a way to write something like:

```
    for data:xml.etree.Element in root.findall('./data'):
```

Comment: I would recommend using a better text editor for python. Additionally, python is strongly typed, but not statically typed.

Comment: Pycharm IDE to rescue!

Comment: I am using PyCharm/IntelliJ

Comment: You can also look at MyPy for that. [here's a nice article I found](http://pawelmhm.github.io/python/static/typing/type/annotations/2016/01/23/typing-python3.html) that talks exactly about the problems of dynamic types and possible solutions (libraries for type annotations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to force vanilla PyCharm to think of it as something, however, it does incur overhead:

```
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(x).getroot()
        for data in root.findall('./data'):
            if isinstance(data, xml.etree.ElementTree.Element):
                data.
```

By wrapping it in `if isinstance()`, PyCharm will infer it's type and let you use auto-completion.

It's not ideal, but that's Python *shrug*